# How to have 2 submit button outside of form antd

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I have a form in antd desing.
I want to have 2 buttons the first one is the main save button and the second is next button.

Inside the form there are required fields, the purpose is to make required field check on next button too and if validation not pass don't allow to go to the next page, if validation is pass grab all fields value and pass to the next page.

I tried this way but the state is changing one step back but cant pass the value directly inside onCLick function and get the necessary values.

[demo link](https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-usage-antd-5-1-5-forked-vrmn4j?file=/demo.tsx)

Comment: Instead of keeping 2 button type as submit you can just attach handlers to both of them. In in the handler you can check if the fields are empty or not

Comment: what you mean attach handlers to both of them?

Comment: Like one function for next button and one function for saving

Comment: And how can I know that this is for submit if I dont mention htmlType?

Comment: then only use submit for your save button

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to validate form fields you can call `form.validateFields()` and check if the promise gets resolved or rejected.

```
const [form] = Form.useForm();

return (
   <Form
      form={form}
      onFinish={(values) => {...}}
      scrollToFirstError
   >
     ...
     <Button 
        onClick={() => {
           form.validateFields()
           .then(() => {
              // all good go to next step
           })
           .catch(() => {
              // form validation failed
           })
        }
     >
        Next
     </Button>
     <Button htmlType="submit">Save</Button>
   </Form>
)
```